# MySQL stored procedure passing array of number in parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, where-clause

I'am not sure what I've been doing wrong ...

I have a simple query :

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

now I just took that query and made it into a store procedure with an arguments of type LONGTEXT

```
sp_FetchMultipleLocations(IN argLocations LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (ID IN (argLocations));
END;
```

then I call that stored procedures with multiples values in that parameters :

```
CALL sp_FetchMultipleLocations('1, 2, 3, 4, 5');
```

but the IN statement in the where clause doesn't seem to be working, it shows me only the first(1) location ... why is that ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument is a single monolithic string. Just because you're using that argument in an `IN` clause inside the sproc doesn't mean MySQL knows it should tear apart that csv string into individual values - it has no idea what CSV is, nor should it.

You'll have to use dynamic sql, e.g. in pseudo-ish code:

```
procedure foo(in args longtext)
begin
    sql = concat('SELECT ... WHERE foo IN (', args, ')')
    execute @sql
end
```

Answer (score 1):

found this today on [this page](https://qastack.com.de/programming/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

```
SET @c = 'xxx,yyy,zzz';
SELECT * from table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(columnname,@c);
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a split function, do it by comma.

The way you pass it now is a single string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ? the stored procedure is begin called form a report (crystal report).